# Can we pass a template lambda function to another lambda function

Tags: c++, json, lambda, c++17, c++20

I have the following code :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct OperatorInterface{
    virtual std::string operator[](std::string str) = 0;
    
};

class RestApi{
    public:
     using func_sig = std::function<void(const int, OperatorInterface*)>;
     virtual void register_get(func_sig&& functor) = 0;
     virtual void apply_get(const int req, OperatorInterface*) = 0;
     // here we could extend further to put, delete, post etc.
};

class RestApiImpl : public RestApi{
    func_sig m_get_method;
    public:
    void register_get(func_sig&& functor) {
       m_get_method = std::move(functor);
    }
    void apply_get(const int req, OperatorInterface* interface){ 
        m_get_method(req, interface);  
    }
};


class ASpecificJSONLibrary{
    
    public:
    std::string operator[](std::string key){
        return key + "_withLambda";
    }
};

class Server{
public:
   ASpecificJSONLibrary* libObj; // this is a 
   Server(){
     libObj = new ASpecificJSONLibrary();
   }
   
   void run(RestApi* api){
      api->apply_get(0, new impl(*this)) ; 
      
   }

   struct impl : public OperatorInterface {
        public:
        Server& m_server;
        impl(Server& server ) : m_server(server){}
        std::string operator[](std::string key) override{
            return (*m_server.libObj)[key];
            
        }
   } ;


};

int main(){

    RestApi* api = new RestApiImpl();
    api->register_get([](int i,  OperatorInterface* intf ){ 
            std::string dummy = "dummy";
        std::cout << (*intf)[dummy];
    } );
    
    
    Server* server= new Server();
    server->run(api);
    

    return 0;
};
```

The motivation and goal for this design is to hide the details for what JSON library I am using. In essence, I dont want my RestAPI implementation to know about the underlaying detail of what Json library I am using.

Currently, I  basically have just added another interface to the `apply_get` function which then implements its own operator, accesses the json value from the specific library and returns the value as string (for now just a dummy illustration above `ASpecificJSONLibrary`).

My question is if there is an alternative (more performant) solution to passing an interface to the lambda function and therefore avoid having to make two virtual functions for each time the `run` method is executed by e.g. templating a lambda function?
The goal is to be able to use the specific json libray as part of executing the RestAPI get method, for example, use the operator[] to get the values for each key, but by avoiding having to add another virtual function.

The Server class knows at compile time which json library to use and therefore I was wondering whether this could be exploited in conjuntion with templates

Comment: It seems the queston doesn't require all this code. Please remove all code not related to the question.

Comment: I think it does if you want to compile it

Comment: The code in the question doesn't compile. Please make a [mre]. You don't need a JSON library to show your intent, do you?

Comment: It compiles now. Are you referring to ASpecificJSONLibrary . Then, yes you need that since this shows an example of me using an implementation detail of a library object. 

I could take it off and then just stop at the operator [] inside the server class, but I am also certain some would either suggest something that does not fit my intent or ask for the motivations.

Comment: Better, but I'm still a bit confused about all this code. _"Can we pass a template lambda function to another lambda function"_  sounds like it wouldn't require more than 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: I did not say the solution had to be straight forward ;).    But essentially I am really not happy with having two virtual per run execution , and had a feeling that by using some templates we could get this deduced at compile time. Since the Server class is quite clear about what it wants to do, i.e. which json library to use. The only thing isn how can that json library object be used inside the Rest API method

Comment: I don't fully understand how you intend to use it, but yes, you can pass templated lambda in the same way as any other lambda, because any of them is object of some _non-templated_ compiler-generated type, whereas it's this type's `operator()` that may be templated. And you can call it directly: `lambda.template operator()<TempArgs...>(Args...);`. There's no special nicer syntax (yet) like with non-templated lambdas though.

Comment: But would that work in the context of  register_get. I could not get it to work by defining a template version when invoking `api->register_get( LAMBDA )`

Comment: Well, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dceosd48r) is one way you can write something similar with templates and concepts and virtual functions, but I'm not quite sure it fits what you need.

Comment: Wauw, wait a minute! Am I understanding this correct? 

By using a "OperatorLike auto" as an argument to the lambda function (or even the apply_get method with another concept) , you are actually just telling the lambda I will be passing something adhering to that concept but by using auto , you are deferring the choice of the actual type? Then, the compiler deduces the actual type? Is that correctly understood?  This was basically what I was looking for. To hide the actual type of the Lambda argument and to minimise the virtual calls.

Comment: Actually, apply_get is a template function in your example, but could that template argument not just be moved as part of the class template.

Comment: So my only comment to your great example is that the RestImpl class is not actually implementing the interface "RestAPI". I am not sure what is the best way to go around that with your example, since the apply_get function is a template function in your example, which is clearly not possible if this function is declared virtual in the RestAPI abstract class

Comment: @sigma any suggestions to how making RestAPI an interface again ?

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay attention to my notifications. The notation with a concept + auto is shorthand for writing a template header with a constrained type parameter, auto just replaces the name of that parameter. So yes, the compiler will deduce the parameter type, but more precisely, it will stop early if you pass a type that doesn't match and tell you which constraint(s) failed.

Comment: And yes, implementing interfaces looks and works differently than through inheritance. So the question is: do you need the inheritance? In my example I used the "Gettable" concept to check that whatever you pass to the server is sufficiently RestAPI-like for that function.

Comment: I ended up making RestAPI non abstract otherwise the code will become too complicated